# Abnormal termination of backup process due to the lesser available space in the hardisk for the backup file

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2000, Data stored in the database is Photo data and text data. I want to take backup of my database but i have a problem of abnormal termination of backup process due to the lesser available space in the hardisk for the backup file. I truncate the log file to create space but still the available space is lesser. How i can take backup of my database? Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Create sufficient space on the drive or backup to a location which does have space? If not possible you might want to look at a third party tool that does backup compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a free utility named [SqlBackupAndFTP](http://www.sqlbackupandftp.com/) (I'm not involved with them)

The backups are zipped so you can save space on disk.
Also, you can schedule and copy backups to a lan or remote site.
It's free for a maximum of two databases

Comment: Does that compress as it goes (as Redgate does) or do the full backup then zip after? Couldn't see that from a quick look.

Comment: Looked at their forum to answer to your comment. Sorry seems that they do __'SQLBackupAndFTP uses standard BACKUP DATABASE command to create standard backup files. After BAK file created, the program zips it into a temporary file, saves on a network or FTPs to a server of your choosing, then deletes temporary file. Then it sends confirmation email to the user.'__

Comment: So I guess the OP will still hit the lack of space issue then.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, right, From another point of view. Is this database used by many people? Have you set the appropriate options for the Recovery Model? How big is the BAK file?

Comment: Thank you Martin Smith and Steve for your valuable guidance.  @Steve, Data File size is 4.5GB and Backup file size may be the same size. The partition size is 8GB, available free space is less then the required. The database is used by more the 03 data entry operators

Comment: @Steve The environment is MS windows advance Server (Domain Server) and window XP on the client side.

Comment: I don't know of any other options but add another disk. (Also an external USB mounted in an empty folder will do, look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967012/external-drive-letter-backup/9968467#9968467) )

Comment: @Steve Your technical information are really amazing and helpful. Now I wants to implement the above in a system where i am facing a problem of newfolder.exe virus, which prevent me to mount USB in a empty folder. So i am in search of safe removal of newfolder.exe virus. The system is not connected to the internet and having old version AVG Free ant virus.Thanks